# Showing this is not a function of bounded variation

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$, defined by $\gamma(t)=t+it\sin(1/t)$ for $t\neq 0$ and $\gamma(0)=0$. Show $\gamma$ is not of bounded variation.

I'm trying to find some partition of $[0,1]$ such that $|\gamma(x_{i+1})-\gamma(x_i)|\ge 1/i$, or something like that. I want to use the series $\sum1/i$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Can anyone help me to give this partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve coincides with the graph of the function $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$. It is oscillating near $0$. It seems reasonable to choose as the $t_k$ the points where $\sin(1/t)=\pm1$:
$$
t_k=\frac{1}{\pi/2+k\,\pi},\quad k=1,2,\dots
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much, that's exactly what I want but I couldn't find.